How to create a dynamic date slicer against pivot table
I have a dataset that's in column wise from a database which is integrated to Power BI. See sample here



Date
Male
Female




2020/03/13
3
1


2020/04/20
6
3



How can I pivot the data to this below so that I can use a date slicer to interact with the table visual:



Date
Gender Count
value




2020/03/13
2
4


2020/04/20
2
9




How do you define Gender Count? Is that the number of Male/Female columns having a nonzero value?  If so, I suggest that you first UNPIVOT your data to get it in the form Date, Gender, and Value.  (Search for "unpivot". There are many articles, tutorials, and examples out there.) From there, you can group by Date and calculate COUNT(NULLIF(Value, 0)) and SUM(Value).  The NULLIF() function will exclude zero values from the count. You could also use conditional aggregation to accomplish the same thing with COUNT(CASE WHEN Value > 0 THEN 1 END).

data
CREATE TABLE yourtable(
   Date   DATE  NOT NULL 
  ,Male   INTEGER   
  ,Female INTEGER  
);
INSERT INTO yourtable
(Date,Male,Female) VALUES 
('2020/03/13',3,1),
('2020/04/20',6,3);

query you don't need pivot just use IIF
select Date
,iif(Male is null or Male=0 ,0,1)+ iif(Female is null or Female=0,0,1) 'Gender Count'
,coalesce(Male,0)+coalesce(Female,0) as value 
from yourtable

dbfiddle

You appear to be checking a non-nullable column for null, which will always give you a gender count of 2. I think you need to check for non-zero.  Perhaps iif(Male > 0, 1, 0) + iif(Female > 0, 1, 0) as 'Gender Count' - fiddle (with additional test data).

apprecited the mension.corrected

I think I didn't structure the data from the screenshot. I will share the updated data sample. Thanks for your support.

Dear @ChibuzoNwankwo upgrade data and then I will change the answer based on it.
